# Why is IntelliJ IDEA building a larger jar file for two projects with exactly the same contents?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, executable-jar

I have created two IntelliJ IDEA projects (test and Test2) with Scala sbt. The dependencies were included via sbt.

***File > new > project > Scala (installed plugging) > sbt > next ...***

The two projects are exactly the same (code copied from test to Test2) but the jar files they build are ~80mb for test and ~120mb for Test2.

I have extracted both the jar files and found that Test2.jar has way more stuff in it than test.jar.

*test*
[test.jar extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMLnR.png)

*Test2*
[Test2.jar extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwDrn.png)

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is a way to correct it? However, both the jar files work as expected.

Please let me know if you need information. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Adding the build.sbt

test..

```
name := "test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
```

Test2..

```
name := "Test2"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit might be your test dependencies not being marked with the test configuration % test

If you want a dependency to show up in the classpath only for the Test configuration and not the Compile configuration, add % "test"

Share your build.sbt, that might help pin point

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1" % Test,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. Added the build.sbt in the original question.